# {{ page.path }} returns empty string on GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Jekyll v1.0.0 provides `page.path` variable to get post's filename. [Documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#page_variables).

On localhost it works fine, but when I push it on [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com), `page.path` always evaluates as empty string.

GitHub Pages [uses](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages) same Jekyll v1.0.0 as I on localhost.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually everything gone fine. May be GitHub finally updated all their components.